# while retrieving the image from the DB only the first image is getting displayed in all the row

Tags: java

When i retrieve the image from the DB only the first image
 what is inserted is displayed in all the row,
 The second and third image  is not been retrieved ,
 i had attached the screen shot as well for reference.
 When i checked the DB all the images are inserted successfully.

**New.html**

This is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body><form action="emp" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
Employee ID: <br>
<input type="text"  size="20"  name="id">
<br>
Employee First Name :  <br>
<input  type="text" size="20" name="fname">
<br>
Employee Last Name :<br>
<input type="text" name="lname"><br>
Date of Birth :<br>
<input  type="date" name="ddate"><br>
Image Upload:<br>
<input  type="file"  name="myfile"><br>
<script>
function myfunction()
{
 var x=document.    getElementById("myfile")
}

</script>
<input  type="submit"  value="Submit">
<iframe  name="ifs" src="display" style="width:550px; height:300px" >  </iframe>

 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Emp.java**

This is my code to insert the data's into the DB and this was inserted successfully.

```
package form;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;

/**
 *   Servlet implementation class emp
 */
 @WebServlet("/emp")
 @MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)
 public class emp extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public emp() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see Servlet#getServletConfig()
 */
//public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return null;
//}

/**
 * @see Servlet#getServletInfo()
 */
//public String getServletInfo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return null; 
//}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

    String id=request.getParameter("id");  
    String firstname=request.getParameter("fname");
    String lastname=request.getParameter("lname");
    String date=request.getParameter("ddate");
    //String imagename=request.getParameter("myfile");


    InputStream  input=null;
    Part load=request.getPart("myfile");

    input=load.getInputStream();




    //InputStream fileupload= null;
    //Part  doc=request.getPart("mydoc");
    //fileupload=doc.getInputStream();
    //byte[]  file=new byte[fileupload.available()];
    //fileupload.read(file);

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection y=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fileupload","root","password");
        PreparedStatement  x=y.prepareCall("insert into empimage values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        x.setString(1, id);
        x.setString(2,firstname);
        x.setString(3,lastname);
        x.setString(4,date);
        x.setBlob(5,input);
        //x.setString(5,imagename);
        //x.setBytes(5,file);
        x.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Date inserted");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("new.html").include(request, response);

    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

}

**Display.java**

This is my display code to display all the information that was inserted in the data base

```
   package form;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.OutputStream;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
  import java.sql.ResultSet;
  import java.sql.SQLException;
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
  import com.mysql.jdbc.Blob;

  /**
   * Servlet implementation class display
  */
  @WebServlet("/display")
  public class display extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 /**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
 public display() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at:  ").append(request.getContextPath());

    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter(); 
    //ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fileupload","root","password");
    PreparedStatement  pre=con.prepareCall("select id,firstname,lastname,DOB from fileupload.empimage");
    //select * from fileupload.empimage
    ResultSet  rs=pre.executeQuery();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    //out.println("<title> Display Data </title>");
    /*out.println("<style>");
    out.println("<table>");
    {
        out.println("<table font-family:arial,sans-serif;>");
        out.println("<table border-collapse:collapse;>");
        out.println("<table width:100%;>");
    }

    out.println("<td><tr>");   
    {
        out.println("<td,th border:1px solid #dddddd;>");
        out.println("<td,th text-align: left;>");
        out.println("<td,th padding: 8px;>");
    }
    out.println("</style>");*/
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<table style=width:100%;height:auto;>");
    out.println("<tr><th>id</th><th>fname</th><th>lname</th><th>date</th><th align='center'> image </th></tr>");
    while(rs.next())
        {
        out.println("<tr>");
        int id=rs.getInt(1);
        out.println("<td>" + id + "</td>" );
        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString(2) + "</td>" );
        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString(3) + "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString(4) + "</td>");
        out.println("<td style='width:150px; height:125px;'><img src="+ "retrieve?"+ id +" style='width:150px;height:125px;'</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
            }   


   // o.write(imgdata);
    //o.flush();
    //o.close();

    out.println("</table>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");


    }


catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }








    }

   /**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
   }

   }
```

Retrieve.java

This is my code to retrieve the image from the data base and display in the table.

```
   package form;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
   import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
   import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
   import com.mysql.jdbc.Blob;

    /**
    * Servlet implementation class retrieve
    */
    @WebServlet("/retrieve")
    @MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)
    public class retrieve extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
    * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
    */
    public retrieve() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     }

    /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());


    Blob image=null;
    byte[] rawbyte=null;

    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    try
    {

        //response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");


        //String id=request.getQueryString();
        //out.println("query string" + id);

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fileupload","root","password");
        PreparedStatement  pre=con.prepareCall("select  image from fileupload.empimage");
        //pre.setInt(0,Integer.parseInt(id));
        ResultSet  rs=pre.executeQuery();
        //int id=rs.getInt(1);
        //pre.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(id));
        rs.next();

        rawbyte=rs.getBytes(1);
        out.write(rawbyte);
        out.flush();
        pre.close();

        }

  catch(Exception e)
    {

    e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }

   /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
  }

  }
```

[displayed output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQYDj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess if you are calling doget() method from Display class and as your code is as below:

```
        <img src="+ "retrieve?"+ id +" style='width:150px;height:125px;'</td>");
```

so here you have passed the parameter id to retrieve api, but in Retrieve.java class that parameter is not used.

In short you need to update your query as

```
select  image from fileupload.empimage where id=<the parameter>
```

Hope this post will help you

Answer (score 0):

In your retriever, you should use the `id` parameter from the HTTP request :

```
String query = "select image from fileupload.empimage where id = ?";
PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareCall(query);
pre.setString(1,request.getParameter("id"));
ResultSet rs = pre.executeQuery();
```

Comment: When i use the "id" to retrieve the image as the above code you have stated       String id=request.getQueryString();
   out.println("query string" + id);    //the getQueryString throws null value , Even i tried with "GET" method as well it did'nt worked out , kindly suggest anything to solve this